Google spread sheet IMPORTRANGE Filters
I am using below formula to import data from another sheet
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet1!I:S"),"select * where Col1 = 'May-24'")
Need to add one more condition as Col2 = 'USA'"
How can we use filters? or any other solution for this
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet1!I:S"),"select * where Col1 = 'May-24'")

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

Use and operator. Try-
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet1!I:S"),"select * where Col1 = 'May-24' and Col2='USA'")

